# PHP Contact Form, not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have been trying to make my first contact form and after hours of googling I can't seem to find the error in my code why it's not working.

My php code:

```
<?php
$to = 'llavert@gmail.com'; 
$from = strip_tags($_POST['email']); 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$adress = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
$city = strip_tags($_POST['city']);
$subject = strip_tags($_POST["subject"]);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
print_r(error_get_last());
```

?>

My html form:

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php">
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Naam *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 Email" name='email' placeholder='Email *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 name" name='address' placeholder='Straat en huisnummer *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 Email" name='city' placeholder='Postcode en gemeente *'/>
                        <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='subject' placeholder='Onderwerp *'/>
                        <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='message' placeholder='Bericht aan BDS bvba *'></textarea>
                        <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="clear"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Formulier legen</a></li>
                                <li class="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Bericht sturen</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: PS yes I know myemail@mailadress.com has to be my actual email.

Comment: You are checking for `$_POST['adress']` but the form element is `address`

Comment: Try print_r(error_get_last()) if mail returns false. Might give you an idea on where you went wrong.

Comment: Let me 'address' that error and see if it works :p

Comment: If I go to the mailer.php on my domain it says the succession sentence 'Email verzonden' meaning email has been sent.

But when I fill in the form nothing happends when I press the button. Also no errors seem to pop up

Comment: @suppko after adding a header I get this, php file in main post editted so you can see it

Error: Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => Undefined index: message [file] => /home/a8234820/public_html/mailer.php [line] => 8 )

Comment: try replacing your                                                                                 `<textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='message' placeholder='Bericht aan BDS bvba *'></textarea>`   to                                                                                                                   `<input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='message'/>
`

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

It is most likely that your local mail server is not set up correctly.

Comment: I'm currently using a free webhosting server to test it, do you recommend anything else to test it with?

Comment: What is the output of

`ini_get("SMTP");` ?

And is there any documentation for the mailing available on your webhost?

Comment: http://www.000webhost.com/ it said it had web mail.

Comment: As I see now it has no SMTP server for free users

Comment: The [000 webhost forum] (http://www.000webhost.com/forum) may be a better place to ask this question.